# Timeout error while accessing same OBIEE webservice from different location

Tags: timeout, apache-axis, webservice-client, obiee

We have an application which is consuming OBIEE webservices to get data. Our application's development team is located at two different locations i.e. SanJose(CA) and Bangalore(Ind).
When we set up the local environment at SanJose everythings works fine and there is no issue at all.

But when we try setting up the local devlopment environment at Bangalore, we are getting Read timeout exception. We thought of this might be a Firewall restriction issue, but there is no such restriction as such(confirmed with the network team)

We are using Tomcat6.0 and java6. Fixing this issue is very much urgent for us to meet our deadline. Please help to show us a way which we can follow and fix this.

The exception stack trace is as follows:

```
[INFO] Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://<SOME-OBIEE-SERVER>/analytics/saw.dll?SoapImpl=webCatalogService]
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
```

Answer (score 1):

"Read timed out" means that the client connected to the remote server and sent the request. But the client didn't receive a response from the server before a timeout expired. Axis2 clients use a default timeout of 30 seconds, although the timeout can be changed.

The people running the web service should be able to tell whether they can see the client connecting and how long it takes the service to respond to the client's request. If the web service is slow to respond, then maybe you just need to increase your client timeout. Alternately, if the service is responding promptly to the request, then I'd look for something like a firewall blocking the return traffic. A quick test might be to access the web service URL through a web browser, or to send a deliberately bad request to the service and see if you get an error back.